# I live in New Zealand and have a job offer from an Australian company. It's a remote position. Can I stay in New Zealand and work?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, irish-citizens

Irish national living in NZ.

I have a working holiday visa and it runs out in September. Can I apply for a New Zealand Visa with a remote job? Should I get paid in Euro into my European account ? Very confused. Amazom voucher for my helper ☺

Comment: Hi Dara, this site is more about travel questions, think tourism and such, you should probably ask this on [Expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) as it relates to staying long term and working

Comment: Also, please can you ask one question at a time? Make each question separate.